# Pandas Data Frame, Select Subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I put this code into one line?

```
game = data[(data.date==test_day)]
game = game.loc[game.index[0]]
```

Comment: data[(data.date==test_day)].loc[game.index[0]] ?

Comment: no, that fails.  there is no game variable created yet to get an index from... this also fails, data[(data.date==test_day)].loc[data.index[0]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `iloc` instead

```
data[data.date == test_day].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just writing the same thing

```
game = data[(data.date==test_day)].iloc[game.index[0]]
```